# How to display the uploaded videos from the server, back inside div tag of the website? Also I want to give social-sharing options on each video?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5-video, socialshare

How to display only specific files[.mp4] uploaded videos[using a foreach loop condition] from the server, back inside div tag of the website? Also I want to give social-sharing options on each video?

```html
<section>
<div id ="getFile">
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#getFile").html('');
$("#getFile").html('<video src="pathto/myserver/video.mp4" controls></video>');

</script>  
</div>
</section>
```

Social-sharing options on each video for:
1.Facebook
2.Twitter
3.YouTube
4.Google Plus
5.Instagram

I think this can be achieved using a combination of JQuery and PHP both, although I am not sure as a newbie.

I want to use the php to display the uploaded files inside div possibly by using a for loop, and the recently uploaded files to appear in the (newest first) order. My html file code is also given.

I am using PHP as my back-end. Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
//my php file//

<?php 

$resource = opendir('resources/uploadFiles/');

//loop for all files
while(($entry = readdir($resource)) !== False) {
if($entry !='.' && $entry !='..')
{
echo($entry)."<br />";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To append a new video into html:

```js
$("#getFile").html('<video src="address of the uploaded-folder on server" controls></video>');
```

I am not sure about what you want in social sharing.

Comment: at the same time when/where you are loading video from server

Comment: This code works, but the video width is going out of the web main wrapper. see the updated code and please check it , as I am a newbie, so please check it and tell me if I am wrong in any way.

Comment: how to **perform this task inside a looping condition** so all the videos from the server are dispalyed as I have a multiple file upload input. thanks